# Criar um serviço junto com o app Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, processo, background, services

Estou desenvolvendo um novo projeto utilizando o ***Ruby on Rails*** para se comunicar com um sistema legado feito em COBOL. Essa comunicação ira ser feita através de arquivos TXT, ou seja, quando eu tenho que pegar informação eu tenho que ler uma pasta, abrir os arquivos TXT e processar. Caso queira gravar enviar informação eu tenho que gravar em arquivo TXT em outra pasta que a aplicação se encarrega do resto.

Como ler e gravar o TXT eu já consegui implementar, minha dúvida é:

Como implementar no Rails um processo ou serviço que fique rodando em *background*, neste processo eu configuro que acada tempo determinado ele verifica se há arquivos TXT em um determinado diretório, ler o conteúdo, processar, mover ou excluir o arquivo TXT. Outro processo que tenho que implementar é verificar se há informações para que eu possa exportar em TXT para o sistema legado.

Apenas ressaltando esse processo tem que se ativar quando a app do Rails for iniciada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o cron, a gem whenever ajuda bastante.